# Label missing values as any other strings

Tags: r, label, na, r-haven

I create a labelled column with `haven`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(haven)

df <- tibble(x = labelled(c(1:3, NA), c('a' = 1, 'b' = 2, 'missing' = NA)))

# # A tibble: 4 × 1
#           x
#   <int+lbl>
# 1     1 [a]
# 2     2 [b]
# 3     3
# 4    NA
```

I seems that the missing value fails to be labelled. I expect to see somthing like

```r
# # A tibble: 4 × 1
#           x
#   <int+lbl>
# 1     1 [a]
# 2     2 [b]
# 3     3
# 4    NA [missing]
```

In addition, `as_factor` gives

```r
as_factor(df$x)

# [1] a    b    3    <NA>
# Levels: a b 3 missing
```

but I want

```r
# [1] a    b    3    missing
# Levels: a b 3 missing
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [`haven::tagged_na`](https://haven.tidyverse.org/reference/tagged_na.html):

```r
x <- labelled(c(1:3, tagged_na("x")), c('a' = 1, 'b' = 2, "missing" = tagged_na("x")))

<labelled<double>[4]>
[1]     1     2     3 NA(x)

Labels:
 value   label
     1       a
     2       b
 NA(x) missing
```

Works as intended with `as_factor`:

```r
as_factor(x)
#[1] a       b       3       missing
#Levels: a b 3 missing
```

Comment: I cannot get what you show with your code. It seems that `tagged_na()` cannot take an empty string as input. If I replace `tagged_na("")` with `tagged_na("x")`, `tibble(x)` and `as_factor(x)` works as I expect. Thanks for help!

Comment: I have `haven 2.5.1` so that may explain the different behavior. Anyway, you can use it with `"x"` or any other letter indeed. I edited the answer to make more coherent

Answer (score 1):

We could use `fct_explicit_na()` from `forcats` package:

```
library(dplyr)
library(haven)
library(forcasts)

df1 <- df %>% 
  mutate(x = fct_explicit_na(as_factor(x), na_level = "missing"))

levels(df1$x)

[1] "a"       "b"       "3"       "missing"
```